# how to dynamically invoke web service at runtime to window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to dynamically invoke web service at run time to window Phone 7.

Comment: What is the difference between dynamically invoking something and statically invoking it?.   Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give any specific answer since the question is quite vague. However, download the `Weather Forecast` sample code from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which focuses on consuming web services.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web service and the handled data, you can use the good old [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and/or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).